# Unity Wheel Collider moves REALLY SLOWLY

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working with Unity's Wheel Collider for a vehicle simulation. Despite using realistic values for mass, drag, and torque, the vehicle moves much slower than expected. As can be seen in the attached video and images, the tires do not appear to be slipping.

[Video of the issue](https://youtu.be/67DIlx6ea9E?si=5G839w0yZ4trhkir)

[Car body rigidbody](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrW1w.png)

[Motor component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdi0J.png)

[Wheel collider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3fOo.png)

```java
// Tesla.cs
public class Tesla : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private new Rigidbody rigidbody;

    [SerializeField]
    private Servomotor steerServomotor;

    [SerializeField]
    private Motor powerMotor;

    private bool isForwardGear = true;

    public float SpeedKmph => rigidbody.velocity.magnitude * 3.6f;
    public float MotorTorque => powerMotor.MotorTorque;
    public float BrakeTorque => powerMotor.BrakeTorque;
    public float SteerAngle => steerServomotor.SteerAngle;

    public void Accelerate(float amount)
    {
        powerMotor.MotorTorque = amount;
    }

    public void Brake(float amount)
    {
        powerMotor.BrakeTorque = amount;
    }

    public void Steer(float angle)
    {
        steerServomotor.SteerAngle = angle;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        isForwardGear = true switch
        {
            _ when Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E) => true,
            _ when Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q) => false,
            _ => isForwardGear
        };

        var accelerateAmount = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) switch
        {
            true when isForwardGear => 1f,
            true when !isForwardGear => -1f,
            _ => 0f
        };

        var steerAmount = true switch
        {
            _ when Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) => -1f,
            _ when Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) => 1f,
            _ => 0f
        };

        Accelerate(accelerateAmount);
        Brake(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) ? 1f : 0f);
        Steer(steerAmount);
    }
}
```

```java
// Motor.cs
public class Motor : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private WheelCollider[] wheels;

    [SerializeField]
    private float torqueMultiplier;

    private float motorTorque;
    private float brakeTorque;

    public float MotorTorque
    {
        get => motorTorque;
        set
        {
            motorTorque = value * torqueMultiplier;
            var wheelMotorTorque = motorTorque / wheels.Length;

            foreach (var wheel in wheels)
            {
                wheel.motorTorque = wheelMotorTorque;
            }
        }
    }

    public float BrakeTorque
    {
        get => brakeTorque;
        set
        {
            brakeTorque = value * torqueMultiplier;
            var wheelBrakeTorque = brakeTorque / wheels.Length;

            foreach (var wheel in wheels)
            {
                wheel.brakeTorque = wheelBrakeTorque;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        foreach (var wheel in wheels)
        {
            wheel.ConfigureVehicleSubsteps(5f, 12, 15);
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        var circumFerence = 2f * Mathf.PI * wheels[0].radius * wheels[0].transform.lossyScale.y;
        var speedOnKmh = circumFerence * wheels[0].rpm * 60f / 1000f;
        Debug.Log($"Wheel 0 Speed: {speedOnKmh} km/h");
    }
}
```

```java
// Servomotor.cs
public class Servomotor : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private WheelCollider[] wheels;

    [SerializeField]
    private float steerAngleMultiplier;

    private float steerAngle;

    public float SteerAngle
    {
        get => steerAngle * steerAngleMultiplier;
        set
        {
            steerAngle = value;
            foreach (var wheel in wheels)
            {
                wheel.steerAngle = steerAngle * steerAngleMultiplier;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I attempted to remove the drag, but car still moved so slowly. Also I attempted to increase the motorTorque, but this led to tire slipping. In response, I adjusted the friction parameters, increasing the slip, value, and stiffness. These adjustments reduced the slipping to some extent, but it still occurred. My expectation was that by tuning these parameters, I would achieve a balance where the vehicle moves at a realistic speed without excessive tire slip.

Comment: Don't forget that EV is thousands of pounds heavier than a normal car.  Its a big enough difference there are reports of parking garage floors collpasing due to the lack of support to handle such heavy machines.  That being said, I don't know if you put that into your calculations, but if you are going for realism, its a component.

Comment: @easleyfixed Thank you for your insight. I've experimented with weights between 1000kg and 3000kg, but unfortunately, the vehicle is still not moving as fast as I'd expect. I'd appreciate any further advice or suggestions you might have.

Comment: Well, first if you have an idea of how fast it should be going, do that calculation to get what you are expecting, then use what you have and have it calculate the values it is assuming, compare those two values to find the difference, then you are onto the next stap at least to find why its getting that value by comparing to things in your formula, and maybe the issue will be more visible as to why and how its getting this calculation instead of that one.  (Note - the have it calculate means do it in the code, and display the results as values you can see so you can see what its using.

Comment: You can also try other tests, try a drop ramp and test accelartion there.  Try an incline and compare the even slower results, but point is, gather data to compare with and that is the first step.  But try different things like this to see if you can force it to work outside the normal operations, then normalize your normal operations if that makes sense.

Comment: how fast were you thinking? as by my calculations thats 13.6mph thats about twice human rumning speed...

Comment: @easleyfixed Thank you for your helpful suggestion! It's been really valuable for my project.

Comment: @BugFinder I'm actually aiming for the vehicle to accelerate from 0 to 60 mph in about 4 seconds, without tire slipping.